# Select User to User messages in sqlalchemy 2

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to select user to user messages with join statements in sqlalchemy 2.0

models.py

```
class User(PaginatedAPIMixin, UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    messages_sent: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Message'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.sender_name', back_populates='author')
    messages_received: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Message'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.recipient_name', back_populates='recipient')

class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    sender_name: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey(User.username), index=True)
    recipient_name: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey(User.username), index=True)
    _body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.Text)
    timestamp: so.Mapped[datetime] = so.mapped_column(index=True, default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    author: so.Mapped[User] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.sender_name', back_populates='messages_sent')
    recipient: so.Mapped[User] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.recipient_name', back_populates='messages_received')
```

routes.py

```
@bp.route('/messages/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def messages(username):
    query = current_user.messages_received.select().where(Message.sender_name == username).order_by(Message.timestamp.desc())    
    messages = db.paginate(query, page=page, per_page=current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
    next_url = url_for('main.inbox', page=messages.next_num) if messages.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('main.inbox', page=messages.prev_num) if messages.has_prev else None
    return render_template('messages.html', title=_('Messages'), messages=messages.items, sender=username, next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

The query works for messages received. I tried the [Joining to Subqueries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#joining-to-subqueries) syntax from SQLAlchemy 2.0 but got confusing errors. Is this the right syntax to select sent and received messages between 2 users?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like maybe you want "All messages sent to the current user from another user specified by `username`."  Is that correct?

Comment: Looking for the syntax to query messages between user1 and user2 ordered by timestamp to display a conversation. Something like 
`query = current_user.messages_received.select().where(Message.sender_name == user2).join(current_user.messages_sent.select().where(Message.recipient_name == user2)).order_by(Message.timestamp.desc())`